# Firefox: unblock JavaScript alerts on specific website

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, alert

I have entered code into the developer console here on StackOverflow to test some code that shows an `alert();` on focus and switched between tabs. Then I clicked the message away but it immediately returned because the `window.onfocus` event seemed to have turned into an infinite loop. I was writing an answer for which I wanted to test the code and that's why I didn't want to reload the page as all progress would be lost. So I clicked the checkbox "Block future requests from stackexchange.com" that was displayed when the message popped up the second time and got rid of the message by doing so.
Now I have a problem: If I now want to cause an `alert();`, I get no alert and the return value is `undefined`, without any error.
I then searched the internet on how to unblock js alerts in firefox but the only thing I found that came even close to what I need was a ton of tutorials on how to unblock WebPush requests.
Is there a way to unblock `alert();`s? If it involves about:config or manually editing config files, no problem.

I am on Linux Mint, so Windows paths to those files won't help me. But you can include them for Windows users who might read this and have the same problem.

This is the code I entered:

```
window.onfocus = function() { alert('example'); return; };
```

Comment: Alerts are horrible UX anyway. Use console logs.

Comment: This is the first hit in [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=don't+allow+x+to+prompt+you+again): [Undoing "don't allow \[website\] to prompt me"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1351901)

Comment: Not the question, but: `alert()` is a bad idea to test/log something - unless you really need that blocking behavior. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @FelixKling That doesn't help. I don't want to unblock the kind of alerts you get with WebPush, as I already said in the question itself. I want to unblock the type of alert the JavaScript function `alert('<string>');` creates.

Comment: @isherwood and @Andreas I might have to do so... But I just want the error messages in the log (to keep it "clean") while just testing and those `alert();`s are usually clicked away with the press of one button.

Comment: Well, I can confirm that closing and starting the browser again, as suggested in the answer I linked to, works. `alert()`s are showing up again. If that's not what you want then please clarify. Even just closing the tab and opening the page again seems to work.

Comment: @FelixKling It didn't work after just restarting the browser... But after 1. closing Firefox via Ctrl+Q, 2. rebooting my laptop, 3. opening Firefox again and going to Menu→History→Restore last session they showed up again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I don't need to worry when I see too much `alert();`s and I click them "permanently" away, as that only lasts until the tab is closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Firefox helps, but for me a reboot of my whole laptop was also necessary (maybe because I didn't restart either Firefox or my computer within the last two weeks?).
Thanks to [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for the help, you can find his comment here: [Firefox: unblock JavaScript alerts on specific website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799244/firefox-unblock-javascript-alerts-on-specific-website?noredirect=1#comment126881829_71799244)